# How to link test results to user story in Azure DevOps (VSTS)?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I want to link test run results to user story to add more traceability on board for all team members.

I've found that I can add link for `New` and `Existing` items, but there I can find only `Work item type`: Bug, Blocker, Epic, Feature, Test Case, User Story etc.

[image]

If I add link to test case, I will see only test case itself (test steps) and can't find any information about this test case in some **test suit** or **test run results**.

I've explored VSTS documentation: [Link user stories, issues, bugs, and other work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/add-link?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [Linking, traceability, and managing dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/link-work-items-support-traceability?view=azure-devops&tabs=new-web-form).

As I understood, there is no such functionality right now in Azure DevOps (VSTS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Developer Community I found opened ticket for it:

[Need ability to link Test Results back to ANY work item type, especially User Stories](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/451436/need-ability-to-link-test-results-back-to-any-work.html?inRegister=true)

I did up vote, but it seems that for now I can only wait for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, currently there is no such thing in Azure DevOps, **but** there is a great extension to add the test run results in the test case.

The (free) extension called [View Latest Test Result](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=keesverhaar.viewlatesttestresult), after you install it you need to modify the process template (to add the results) and then you got this:

[image]

Comment: will this show at User story level as well.. As here i see.. the picture is for test case