# Azure DevOps - Linking one test case to many stories and executing test case just one time

Tags: azure-devops, testcase

I created a test case that cover more than one story, so I linked this test case to all related stories.
The problem is that, when I execute the test case, its result is not replicated to all stories.
It seems like I created many copies of the same test case, so I need to execute each one of them.

My question is: is there a way to link a test case to many stories and execute this test case one time (so, its result would reflect in all related stories)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's the expect behavior, since you linked is a test case work item.

When you run the test case, it will generate a corresponding test run and test run results.

If you add link to test case, you will see only test case itself (test steps) and can't find any information about this test case in some test suit or test run results.

There has been a related user voice in our develop community:

> **Need ability to link Test Results back to ANY work item type, especially User Stories**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/451436/need-ability-to-link-test-results-back-to-any-work.html?inRegister=true

You could vote up and monitor the status. Also have a look at this similar question here: 
[How to link test results to user story in Azure DevOps (VSTS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56445487/how-to-link-test-results-to-user-story-in-azure-devops-vsts)